# What is the correct usage of terms declaration, definition, implementation in OOP?

Tags: oop

I think that the key to good unambiguous question is the use of correct terminology where terms have a good defined meaning. I want to know what is the proper and improper use of terms like *declaration*, *definition*, *implementation*?

Is it correct that the following snippet

```
public class MyClass
{
    // members and methods
}
```

is class declaration or is class declaration just

public class MyClass

and the part in curly brackets is

```
{
     // members and methods
}
```

is definition? Or is it implementation? Or is it definition of implementation? What is the correct terminology here?
Of course, part of definition of implementation is also declaration of member variables or even inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

Those terms don't map well to object oriented programming theory.  They are generally used within the ecosystem of a particular programming language and its syntax, such as declaring a variable, implementing a function or method.  As you learn a particular language, you would learn the lingo of that language and mirror that when communicating to others about your code.